# Как вывести уникальный элемент с массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив в котором полно дублей, и есть всего несколько уникальных элементов как их можно найти при помощи javascripta?
Например массив `t = [ "t","t" ,"arr", "arr", "i" ]`содержит только один уникальный элемент (`i`). Как его вывести ?

Нужно удалить все совпавшие элементы оставить только элемент, который изначально без дублей в массиве.

Например после обработки массива `t = [ "t","t" ,"arr", "arr", "i" ]` - должна остаться только `"i"`;

Или из массива `V = [ "a","a,"vtr", "vtr", "i", "n" ]` - остаются только `"i", "n"`

Comment: элементы простые строки?

Comment: @Grundy, да это простые строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае если элементы простые строки можно использовать функцию [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var t = [ "t","t" ,"arr", "arr", "i" ].reduce(function(map,el){
    if(!map[el]) map[el]=true;
    return map;
},{});
```

Теперь в переменной *t* у нас объект в котором ключи, только уникальные элементы из массива, чтобы получить его, можно воспользоваться функцией [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
t = Object.keys(t);
```

---

Второй вариант, собрать массив сразу в функции [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var t = [ "t","t" ,"arr", "arr", "i" ].reduce(function(acc,el){
    if(!acc.map[el]) {
        acc.map[el]=true;
        acc.result.push(el);
    }
    return acc;
},{map:{},result:[]}).result;
```

---

Для поиска только элементов без дублей, проще всего, посчитать сколько раз встречается элемент, и выбрать только те, который встречаются 1 раз

```js
    var t =  [ "t","t" ,"arr", "arr", "i" ].reduce(function(map,el){
        map[el] = (map[el]||0)+1;
        return map;
    },{});

    var filtered = Object.keys(t).filter(function(el){
      return t[el] == 1;
    })
    
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: спасибо  у меня самого тоже так получилось , просто проблема в том что нужно  оставить только тот элемент  дублей которого в массиве нет вообще. В моем примере должна остаться только i

Comment: @Dementiy1999, добавьте пример выхода в вопрос, чтобы точно было видно какой результат ожидается :-) Как-то я это пропустил в тексте.

Comment: @ Grundy, добавил пример в вопрос)

Comment: @Dementiy1999, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо то что нужно)

Comment: @Dementiy1999, вообще наверное можно и за один проход, но что-то на скорую руку не могу пока придумать

Comment: та и на этом спасибо это я чисто для себя чтоб не считать вручную картинки)